# How to upgrade the gradle of an existing flutter project?

Tags: flutter

Is there any simple way to upgrade the gradle of an existing project in flutter. I did not find any clear way to do it on the net.

Answer (score 0):

If your Android project doesn't have a lot of customizations, just delete the android folder and recreate it by running the following from the root of your project:

> flutter create .

This has been my preference recently. Although I have to recreate the launcher icon and other custom settings in AndroidManifest.xml, I know that I am getting the latest updates Flutter has to offer Android.

Also, if it did'nt work, you can change compileSdkVersion.

Another solution:
[image]
For using VS Code,.. route to android/gradle folder and run: gradle update

Alternative: https://medium.com/@gtxgat/upgrade-gradle-version-professionally-in-flutter-5e0c16305cc0

I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work.